# Regular expression trouble in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I've the following regex in my model

```
 validates :profile_name, presence:true,
                     uniqueness:true,
                     format:
                     {
                       with: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/,
                       message: "Must be formatted correctly"
                     }
```

My tests are not passing because of regex. I am validating the profile name.

Here is my error log:

```
     The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $),
     which may   present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or 
     forgot to   add the :multiline => true option? (ArgumentError)
```

I think am doing right, still it is not passing. Please Help me to fix this.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Show us some of the text you want to test with the regex.

Comment: I want to valid these kind of string includes _ and numbers.
example: prabhkaru_123 or prabhakar.u

Answer (score 1):

Use, `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$` for regex:

```
validates :profile_name, presence:true,
                 uniqueness:true,
                 format:
                 {
                   with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/,
                   message: "Must be formatted correctly"
                 }
```

Read more on [Regular Expressions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#regular-expressions) as to why.